# Assignment of coprime values to a tree

Tags: algorithms, trees, number-theory

I recently saw this question somewhere and thought a lot on it but was unable to find an efficient solution for it.
Asked on Stack Overflow but got no solution there.

The Problem is as follows -

Given a tree with $X$ number of nodes we need to assign values to each node.

You  are also given two arrays `A[]` and `B[]` each of size $X$. Assignment to nodes should be done in such a manner that if you assign number $N$ to some node $i$ then $N$ should lie between `A[i]` and `B[i]`.

Also if two nodes are connected with an edge then they both should be assigned values that are co-prime (GCD = 1). For each node you need to find the sum of all possible values assigned to that node in every possible tree assignment that can be done.

You need to output $X$ numbers, one for each node.

Upper limit on $X$ is $50$.
Upper limit on `A[i]` and `B[i]` is $100000$.

Can somebody suggest an efficient solution to this problem?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/66147/755, http://stackoverflow.com/q/40585441/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.